# jquery ".load" it does not load after adding the content

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, load

I use .load to load HTML code which load photo. It is working well, but when I add more photos (without jquery) on a page than the first photo disappear. Probably will not be able to load... What can I do?

jquery:

```
function uvodni_fotka_load(){

    if(window.innerWidth < 700){
    $(function(){
      $("#uvodni_fotka").load("mobile.html");
    });
    } else {
    $(function(){
      $("#uvodni_fotka").load("normal.html");
    });
    }
}
uvodni_fotka_load();
```

HTML which I want to load (this code is from page where I have photos and working good):

```
<canvas data-prodibi='{"id":"r0265j8w89d9jk","width":5892,"height":2812,"smartX":0.5,"smartY":0.538629,"account":"vitius"}'>
    <script>
        ;
        ! function () {
            if ( window.prodibiAsync == null ) {
                var s = document.createElement( 'script' );
                s.async = !0;
                s.src = 'https://max1.prodibicdn.com/libraries/pages/prodibi.embed.2.0.min.js';
                document.body.appendChild( s );
            }
            window.prodibiAsync = window.prodibiAsync || [];
            prodibiAsync.push( {
                type: "settings",
                settings: {
                    account: "vitius"
                }
            } );
        }();
    </script>
</canvas>
```

Comment: AFAIK, `load` overwrites the content instead of appending. I could be wrong though.

Comment: @Script47 Sounds like it's the other way around, the upload photos function is probably using .html() instead of .append() by default. OP could write a function for when new photos are added to append instead of overwrite.

Comment: `.load()` overwrites the content of the target element. That's for sure. If OP wants to `.append()`, he should look for `.ajax()` where he can do whatever he likes on `success` callback. -- `.load()` is a shorthand... Yeah, with somewhat limited capabilities.

Comment: By the way... `$(function(){...})` (window "ready" event wrapper) is useless in a `if` or/and `else` statement of a named function. That is an horrible syntaxic misuse.